# Map 0-1 values exponentially to a list of shutter speeds

Tags: ios, algebra

I am attempting to a UISlider with a min value of 0 and a max value of 1 to control the exposure of a camera with a minimum shutter speed of 1/2 second and max shutter speed of 1/8192.

Here is the list of shutter values the user will see:
`[2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 30, 40, 50, 64, 96, 128, 192, 240, 384, 480, 768, 1024, 1536, 2048, 4096, 8192]` (all being fractions of a second.)

The problem is, these values can't be mapped linearly.  The difference in exposure is the same 1/2 to 1/4 as it is from 1/4096 to 1/8192.  If it was mapped linearly, 0.5 would equate to roughly 4094, so a one step in shutter difference would take up half of the slider.

I am looking to map the values exponentially instead.  0.5 should roughly equal 128, .25 should equal 16, .75 should equal 6000.

Comment: That sounds great. What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getShutterValue(sliderValue: Double) -> Int {
    return Int(pow(2,Double(1+Int(sliderValue*12))))
}

print(getShutterValue(0))      // 2
print(getShutterValue(0.25))   // 16
print(getShutterValue(0.4992)) // 64
print(getShutterValue(0.5))    // 128
print(getShutterValue(0.75))   // 1024
print(getShutterValue(1))      // 8192
```

---

As asked in comments below: if you want to return shutter values in a continuous span [2.0, 8192.0], you can use the following modified `getShutterValue(..)` function:

```
func getShutterValue(sliderValue: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(2, 1+sliderValue*12)
}

print(getShutterValue(0))      // 2.0
print(getShutterValue(0.25))   // 16.0
print(getShutterValue(0.33))   // 31.12....
print(getShutterValue(0.4992)) // 127.15....
print(getShutterValue(0.5))    // 128.0
print(getShutterValue(0.75))   // 1024.0
print(getShutterValue(1))      // 8192.0
```

Note however that if you choose to use this approach, make sure to take care if you're planning to use the shutter values in some equatable comparison statement (`==`), as floating point numbers have limited precision.

Comment: That's working almost perfect for my case.  I'm wondering if you'd be able to get all the values between 2 and 8192, and not just the powers of 2?

Comment: @IvanLesko Sure, just replace the return statement in the function above with `return Int(pow(2, 1+sliderValue*12))` (i.e., not constraining the exponents to be integers).

Comment: That works perfect, thanks.  Is there a name for this formula?  I'd like to do a bit of research to have a better understanding.

Comment: @IvanLesko My prev. comment shows how to (possibly) return all integer values in the specified span, whereas I now also added a version where you return truly continuous values in this span, in the form of a `Double` return. As to your other question: the `pow(a,b)` function is just returning `a` to the power of `b`, i.e. `pow(a,b)=a^b`. As per the function `getShutterValue(..)` itself, it's just a single exponential function specified to comply to `f: D -> Y`, with `D=[0,1]` and `Y=[2,8192]`: where `D` and `Y` are the input and output spans, respectively, that you specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

8192 = 2 to the 13th power

sliderValue/13 = power

total = 2

for i in 1...power {
    total * 2
}